# Can i pull data of multiple companies using the Alphavantage API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, alpha-vantage

For example, if I want to list out all the stocks on NSE/BSE and their closing price, is there a way to do this without using the API for each individual stock?

Can you pull data of more than one company from the API without using the URL repeatedly. Also if possible can we get the data of all the companies listed in the NSE/BSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. You have to pull each individual stock ticker.